# head of a sequence

Tags: evaluation, hold, sequence, attributes

Why does `Head[Sequence[b, c]]` return `c[Symbol]` and not `Sequence`?

Why does `Head[[b, c]]` return an error: The expression b cannot be used as a part specification

I am trying to determine the behaviour of `Sequence` in Mathematica. It seems an unusual expression.

Comment: Because a rule causes it to evaluate to `Head[b, c]`: Examine `Trace[Head[Sequence[b, c]]]`. (2) `Head[[b, c]]` is short-hand for `Part[Head, b, c]`: examine `FullForm[Head[[b, c]]]`.

Comment: Maeder writes about this in *Programming with Mathematica*. `Sequence[]` often behaves differently when used with other functions due to its special properties, so one needs to do things differently if you're doing things with it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2     That makes sense, this is the splicing rule I read about. Thanks JM I will look up the reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Head[Sequence[b, c]]` returns an error (Head::argx: Head called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected) on my system (MMA 12.0, Win10-64). This makes sense because `Head` has no `Hold` attributes, so `Sequence` is evaluated within `Head`, leading to Head being called with two arguments, i.e. `Head[b, c]`. Look at the `Trace` output:

```
Trace @ Head[Sequence[b, c]]

{HoldForm[Head[Sequence[b, c]]], 
 HoldForm[Head[b, c]], 
 {HoldForm[Message[Head::argx, HoldForm[Head], HoldForm[2]]], .... }
```

You can write your own function that holds sequences:

```
ClearAll[myHead]
myHead[expr_] := Head@Unevaluated@expr
SetAttributes[myHead, SequenceHold]

myHead[Sequence[b, c]]

(* Out: Sequence *)
```

---

As to the second part of your question, `Head[[b, c]]` is interpreted as an application of [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (i.e. `[[...]]`), so MMA thinks that you are trying to take part `(b,c)` of object `Head`.

Comment: Thanks that makes it very clear.